# SQL required data based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been working on a report for the required output. The scenario is that a block manufacturing firm having multiple orders of the same client delivers orders on a credit on different dates and clients pays amount partially irrespective of the orders. I have been stuck in these two tables:

Orders_master,

```
do_no   Client_id   Site_id Order_date  Amount
1       1           1       2013-10-27  50000
2       1           1       2013-10-29  47000
3       1           1       2013-10-15  10000
```

Client_payments,

```
P_id    Client_id   Site_id P_date      Amount
1       1           1       2013-11-05  30000
2       1           1       2013-11-10  67000
3       1           1       2013-11-20  10000
```

I need help to write a query which gives the following output all rows from both tables,

```
Do_no   Client_id   Site_id Order_date  P_date      Order_amount    Payment_amount
1       1           1       2013-10-27  Null        50000           Null
2       1           1       2013-10-29  Null        47000           Null
Null    1           1       Null        2013-11-05  Null            30000
Null    1           1       null        2013-11-10  Null            67000
3       1           1       2013-11-15  Null        10000           Null
Null    1           1       Null        2013-11-20  Null            10000
```

Below query returns all the rows of orders_master table but misses the last row of the required output shows above,

```
select om.*, cp.*
from orders_master om left join
client_payment cp on 
om.order_date = cp.p_date and
om.site_id = cp.site_id
where om.site_id = 1
```

I tried different joins but it does not return all the rows of both the columns, if returns then with repeating values and not nulls

Comment: had u try FULL OUTER JOIN ?

Comment: yes i tried but it returns repeated rows of the first table until it returns all the rows of the linked/child table

Comment: it might be caused by 1 order master have multiple payment info. You might have repeated p_date in your client_payments data. Therefor it satisfy the join, what @GarethD posted should be what you want, please flag it as accepted answer if it is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to use `UNION [ALL]` to combine the two tables, rather than a JOIN:

```
SELECT  do_no,
        client_id,
        site_id,
        Order_Date,
        P_Date = NULL,
        Order_Amount = Amount,
        Payment_Amount = NULL
FROM    Orders_Master
WHERE   Site_ID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  do_no = NULL,
        client_id,
        site_id,
        Order_Date = NULL,
        P_Date = P_Date,
        Order_Amount = NULL,
        Payment_Amount = Amount
FROM    Client_Payments
WHERE   Site_ID = 1;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85369/1)**